# Getting error because of template in Tree class

Tags: c++, templates, tree, insertion

I have a **Tree** class and in this class i have a **Node** class (nested) which is private. The **Tree** class is a template class of course.
The problem is that when I want to insert a tree child into a tree parent that has not the exact number of children, I get an error of not compatible type for conversion.

---

Here is my code:
**tree.hpp**

```
#ifndef TREE_HPP
#define TREE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef> 

template <typename T, char N>
class Tree {
private:
  class Node;
  Node* _info;
public:
  Tree();
  Tree(T, char);
  Tree(const Tree&) = delete;  // copy constructor
  Tree& operator= (const Tree&) = delete; // assignement by copy constructor
  Tree (Tree&&); // transfer constructor
  Tree& operator= (Tree&&); // assignement by transfer constructor
  ~Tree() {delete _info;}
  bool ins(char, Tree&);
  Tree* fils(char);
};

template <typename T, char N>
Tree<T, N>::Tree() 
  : _info(nullptr) {}

template <typename T, char N>
Tree<T, N>::Tree(T data, char size) {
  Node* node = new Node(data);
  _info = node;
}

template <typename T, char N>
Tree<T, N>::Tree(Tree&& t) {
  _info = t._info;
  t._info = nullptr;
}

template <typename T, char N>
Tree<T, N>& Tree<T, N>::operator= (Tree&& t) {
  if (&t != this) {delete _info; _info = t._info; t._info = nullptr;}
  return *this;
}

template <typename T, char N>
bool Tree<T, N>::ins(char index, Tree& childTree){
  if (_info){
    _info->getChildren()[index] = &childTree;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

template <typename T, char N>
Tree<T,N>* Tree<T, N>::fils(char index){
  return _info->getChildren()[index];
}

template <typename T, char N>
class Tree<T, N>::Node {
private:
  T _data;
  Tree* _children[N];
  bool _isWord;
public:
  Node();
  Node(T);
  Tree** getChildren() {return this->_children;}
  T getData(){return this->_data;}
  ~Node() = default;
};

template <typename T, char N> // Node class default constructor
Tree<T,N>::Node::Node(){
  _data = 0;
  _children = nullptr;
  _isWord = false;
}

template <typename T, char N> // Node class constructor
Tree<T,N>::Node::Node(T data){
  _data = data;
  _isWord = false;
  for (char i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    _children[i] = NULL;
}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include "tree.hpp"

#define SIZE 5
#define display(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl
int main() {
  Tree<char,SIZE> n1('A',SIZE);
  Tree<char,SIZE> n1_1('B',SIZE); // works fine
  Tree<char,10> n1_2('C',10); // sends the error
  n1.ins(0,n1_1);
  n1.ins(1,n1_2);
  return 0;
}
```

and the error is:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:12: error: cannot convert ‘Tree<char, '\012'>’ to ‘Tree<char, '\005'>&’
   16 |   n1.ins(1,n1_2);
      |            ^~~~
      |            |
      |            Tree<char, '\012'>
In file included from main.cpp:4:
tree.hpp:80:40: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘bool Tree<T, N>::ins(char, Tree<T, N>&) [with T = char; char N = '\005']’
   80 | bool Tree<T, N>::ins(char index, Tree& childTree){
      |
```

I am also opened to suggestion about ways to improve this code.
Thank you ...

Comment: The change in `N` means the classes are different types. I don't see what you get from having a fixed number of children when clearly you do not want a fixed number of children. I'd remove template `N`  and dynamically allocate the number of children.  Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you are allowed to.

Comment: For completeness you should add the definition for `Node` to the question. Sidenote: See if you can hide `Node` from the user, and definitely don't let them hols a reference to one. It sucks when the user accidentally frees or damages a node because it breaks the whole data structure.

Comment: @user4581301 I did not quite understood what you are saying but i could send a const reference to Node when I want to use Node objects and this case i don't modify node because it is const.

Comment: Assumption: `Node` contains an array of child nodes of size `N`. This means that `Node<5>` has a different size from `Node<10>` and is no longer compatible. What you can do is make a non-templated `Base_Node` class that `Node` inherits from. `Base_Node` declares all of the functions of `Node`, but does not implement them. `Tree` stores and sees pointers to `Base_Node` and knows nothing about how many children, and thus what type of `Node` is actually pointed at. This solves the compatibility problem, but makes it really hard on `Tree` to figure out which `Node` to construct.

Comment: The above will keep the amount of dynamic allocations down to the bare minimum, but does not scale well.

Answer (score 1):

> The Tree class is a template class of course.

A tree is not necessarily a template. Don't do stuff "just because" ;).

`Tree<char,10>` and `Tree<char,5>` are two distinct types. You cannot convert one into the other unless you implement some means to convert them.

It is not clear, why you decided to have the number of nodes children in the tree to be part of the trees type. Adding or removing children would yield you a different type of tree.

Consider `std::array` vs `std::vector`. `std::array` has number of elements as template parameter, because its size cannot ever change. On the other hand, `std::vector` has dynamic size.

Actually I do not see why your `Tree` needs to know about the size of its nodes `children` array. Either I missed it or you never use `N` in `Tree`. I did not follow all the details, but it seems you can safely remove `N` completely from your code and use a `std::vector` for the nodes childrens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here I do need to use template because I dont know the type that will be passed to my tree. Although I am convinced that it is better to remove N and use std::vector.

Comment: @Mohammadreza I didnt want to suggest to not use a template. "I dont know the type that will be passed to my tree" is a good reason to write a template, but you have no good reason to parametrize the template on `N`

Comment: Yeah i am agree . I am gonna remove `N` and use std::vector instead

Comment: But I would like to know if I can choose an index of my vector and assign it to something? Or it is impossible to do such a thing and I am stuck with `push_back()`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a std::vector and only pass N as a parameter to the node? Then you create an insert function in the node that check that max size isn't reached

Comment: i prefer not to use std::vector but I like your idea to pass N as parameter.  Also so just I know, does std::vector allocates the vector on heap or stack?

Comment: @Mohammadreza `vector` allocates dynamically. Heap is a common implementation of Dynamic storage. [Documentation for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: You can use at function on vector to get a reference on element to change it. But you need to check that size of the vector is superior of the element you want to access

Answer (score 0):

When c++ creates an object it creates it staticaly which means that an object with SIZE 4 is a whole diffrent object from the one with SIZE 5.these two objectare nothing alike and you can't trat them as if thy were

Comment: Thank you. I understand now  what to do. I remove N and use std::vector for my `_children`